# Activating Site Features Question

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I Activate a Site Feature under Site Settings within SharePoint 13, does it only activate the Site Feature from my account or does it activate it for anyone else who is using SharePoint? I am not an administrator.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would activate the feature for any account that can access the site - not only for you.

Example: 
If you activate the "Community Site Feature" every user with access to the site can access the discussion board, categories etc (if they have contribute rights).

If you activate the Site Feed feature every user can post on that site's newsfeed (if they have contribute rights).

Things might be different for custom features/solutions depending on the solution.